# Passing jquery variable to php using ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

There is a left side menu consisting of product categories (look down). When you click or hover over a menu item, the valuemenuitem variable (jquery) is assigned one of the values - Kitchen Appliances, Home Appliances, and so on. The value of this variable is sent by an ajax request and depending on the postback result, the right side menu is displayed (using php). How can this ajax request be processed? There is an example. How do you need to redo it?

```
    <?php
class ajaxValidate {

function formValidate() {
    //Put form elements into post variables (this is where you would sanitize your data)
    $field1 = @$_POST['field1'];

    //Establish values that will be returned via ajax
    $return = array();
    $return['msg'] = '';
    $return['error'] = false;

    //Begin form validation functionality
    if (!isset($field1) || empty($field1)){
        $return['error'] = true;
        $return['msg'] .= '<li>Error: Field1 is empty.</li>';
    }

    //Begin form success functionality
    if ($return['error'] === false){
        $return['msg'] = '<li>Success Message</li>';
    }

    //Return json encoded results
    return json_encode($return);
}

}

$ajaxValidate = new ajaxValidate;
echo $ajaxValidate->formValidate();
?>
```

```js
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Ajax Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="info1">
        <li>Put anything in the field below.</li>
    </ul>
    <form id="form1">
        <input type="text" name="field1" id="field1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Form">
    </form>
    <script>
    $('#form1').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $('#info1').html(data.msg);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[MySiteScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPFFc.png)

Answer (score 0):

delete the line
event.preventDefault();
data.msg should be only data